# 500 Error on index.php landing page

Tags: error-500

Good Morning.  We are using ExpressionsEngine 2.0 and a couple of days ago the landing page in /admin/index.php has been returning 500 internal server error.  I did not install of the CMS and I am very new to ExpressionEngine.  It was working about two week ago.   Here is the .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
# Standard .htaccess file

# Secure .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# Don't show any directory without an index file
Options -Indexes

# Dont list files in index pages
IndexIgnore *

# EE 404 page for missing pages
# May differ depending on where your template is located.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?/core/404

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Unfortunately I don't know if this is being used or if the index.php is what is used however I suspect it is the index.php.  this is the only setting I see changed in the index.php file:

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  System Path
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The following variable contains the server path to your
 * ExpressionEngine "system" folder.  By default the folder is named
 * "system" but it can be renamed or moved for increased security.
 * Indicate the new name and/or path here. The path can be relative
 * or it can be a full server path.
 *
 * http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/installation/best_practices.html
 *
 */
        $system_path = './admin';
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Did you follow the installation instructions properly?
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/installation.html

Comment: You would help us greatly by following this guide when asking questions: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/editing-help. I can't understand what you pasted and why.

Comment: I didn't not install this, I inherited it from a previous Admin. I had not heard of Expressions Engine until the problem on Tuesday. Sorry if my question was not clear, when the marketing group attempts to connect to the ExpressionEngine page at domainname.com/landing/admin/index.php they receive a 500 error. This was working for about a year, it was installed in June of 2014. To my knowledge nothing has changed on our site that would have caused this error and I am trying to find any clues to resolve it. Dave

Comment: Dolson - we can't help you without additional information. I get the problem, but suppling the htaccess file contents is of little use. Is the frontend fine (delivering the website)? The Control Panel is normally accessed via a file in the web root (along with the index.php), by default called admin.php - not in the admin folder. Look via FTP and up date your question with information regarding where you admin folder is located and where the admin.php file is. If it's not there, look at your backups or get one from the original EE install. Is there an index.php in the admin folder?

Comment: index.php isn't the problem - that delivers the frontend. The admin.php file delivers the Control Panel.